# Substitute variables script does not work

Tags: bash, sed, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to substitute variables with a script, I confirmed the variables contain valid values. The script runs in the Octopus "Run a Script" step, no errors are shown, but the file doesnt get modified.

I tried running the sed from the terminal directly and it works, however when included in the bash script running from octopus against the target, no substitution happens. I verified permissions are properly set.

```
# This script is for the 'Substitute Application Variables' step in Octopus Deploy 

tokens_key=$(get_octopusvariable "Tokens-Key")
tokens_issuer=$(get_octopusvariable "Tokens-Issuer")
tokens_expiration=$(get_octopusvariable "Tokens-Expiration")
tokens_domain=$(get_octopusvariable "Tokens-Domain")

environment=$(get_octopusvariable "Octopus.Environment.Name")
application=$(get_octopusvariable "ApplicationName")
version=$(get_octopusvariable "Octopus.Release.Number")
deployment_user=$(get_octopusvariable "DeploymentUser")
source_dir="/home/$deployment_user/.octopus/Applications/OctopusServer/$environment/$application/$version"

class_folder="WEB-INF/classes"

cd $source_dir
echo pwd

#extract the classes folder of the archive
echo "unzip $source_dir/$application.war"
unzip "$source_dir/$application".war

echo $tokens_key
echo $tokens_issuer
echo $tokens_expiration
echo $tokens_domain

echo "$class_folder/application.yml"

echo "running sed in $class_folder"
cd $class_folder

#manully replace all the variables
sed -i "s/#{Tokens-Key}/$tokens_key/g" "application.yml"
sed -i "s/#{Tokens-Issuer}/$tokens_issuer/g" "application.yml"
sed -i "s/#{Tokens-Expiration}/$tokens_expiration/g" "application.yml"
sed -i "s/#{Tokens-Domain}/$tokens_domain/g" "application.yml"
```

Inside of application.yml, #{Tokens-Key} should be replaced with the value of the variable $tokens_key, instead the placeholder is not replaced. Same is true for all other place holders.

application.yml

```
security:
  type: cas
  jwt:
    tokens:
      key: #{Tokens-Key}
      issuer: https://#{Tokens-Issuer}
      max-age: #{Tokens-Expiration} # 15min
      cookie-domain: #{Tokens-Domain}
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to the smallest script that still shows the problem you have? (And the minimal input required to demonstrate it.)

Comment: I reduced it quite a bit.

Comment: Can you run the script with `set -x`, make sure to log both stdout and stderr, and post the resulting debug/output log here?

Comment: I think `$class_folder` has space in path, thus `cd $class_folder` enter wrong place.  Change to `cd "$class_folder"`

Comment: @user95488, Have you tried to print value of ${"Tokens-Key"} ? and check the scope of variable also..

Comment: It might has something to do with the escape characters you use in your regex. Try to escape values in `$tokens_key` with `tokens_key=$(echo $tokens_key | sed 's#/#\\/#g')` before using it to replace text in the yml file. But without any errors added to your question, guessing is our only way of helping you.

Comment: Is it maybe just a path issue? e.g. that if it is run from octopus it doesn't find your script (or your script doesn't find the application.yml)? have you already tried to write debug messages to a separate (log)file from your script?